# Nanogest gesture recognition api for ios

Tags: ios, iphone, gesture-recognition

I am trying to do hand gesture recognition for ios devices using front camera.Nano gest is a right step in this direction.But is there a way to get nanogest ios-api.

http://www.nanocritical.com/nanogest/api/

Comment: Can you clarify what you're looking for? The docs appear to support iOS: http://www.nanocritical.com/nanogest/api/ios.html

Comment: I want to get tha api.Is it available for download.

Comment: See my answer below. It does not appear to be available for download. You need to contact Nanocritical.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing and software availability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a free camera gesture SDK available. The few companies I've found require you to contact the company for the SDK.

> #### Licensing
>
> Please contact us for details: nanogest@nanocritical.com.
>
> #### Academic research license
>
> If you are a researcher or a student in an academic institution, we can give you access to the Nanogest SDK
> under a non-commercial research license, at no cost. Please contact us
> for details: nanogest@nanocritical.com.

via http://www.nanocritical.com/nanogest/

Other possible solutions:

- http://www.pointgrab.com/natural-user-interface/
- http://eyesight-tech.com/solutions/
- http://fixational.com/ - Eye-gesture SDK